# Get a list of events owned by a facebook page

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know how I can get a list of events owned (created) by a Facebook page?

I seem to be able to use the "graph api" to generate a list of the events an entity is *attending*. I also looked at FQL, but it seems to require that the 'where' clause is an indexable field (and, naturally, the id is the only indexable field).

For bonus points, we'd be able to do this without any authentication. (Though I'm resigned to the fact that I'm likely going to need at least a permanent access_token.)

If anyone knows how to do this I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All FQL data access requires authentication, so forget about those "bonus points".

This is going to require some post-query handling as, like you said, the FQL `WHERE` clause only respects indexible fields and the `owner.id` field is not indexible. Thus, we first begin by identifying events the user is a "member" of and loading the owner information for those events.

```
SELECT id, name, owner.id FROM event WHERE id IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = XXX)
```

Once the query returns a dataset, we must manually check for rows in which `owner.id` is equal to `uid`.

Comment: This is the answer that really answers the question and should have got the bounty. Unfortunately I was caught away from my PC and couldn't accept the answer on my phone. Sorry Dustin.

Comment: id is not a member of the event table

Comment: owner is not a member of the event table

Comment: Appears they have changed FQL (again). From my tests this still returns the correct results, but I will post an edit with an updated query.

Comment: David, you can't get the owner from fql query. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/ substitute host and creator instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to first query the event_member table, using the uid

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member

and then once you got the eid of the events you can query the events table where the eid is indexed
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event

and I'm sure you can use the first as a subquery of the second query like `var query = FB.Data.query("select name from event where eid in (select eid from event_member where uid = {0})", user_id);`

Comment: Can you get it to work? I get errors because uid isn't indexable.

Comment: see my edits to the answer above. I figure the query would look something like  FB.Data.query("select name from event where eid in (select eid from event_member where uid = {0})", user_id);

Comment: This returns the names of the events that an entity owns, is attending, or has simply been invited to. There has to be another step - see Dustin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This one does it

select eid from event where creator=".$facebookPageId." and eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=".$facebookPageId.") ORDER BY start_time DESC

Answer (score 0):

This link has a good tutorial on FB events and many more on C#.

http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/

But he uses a dll which he created. But as soon as you get the idea out of the blog, you can use Facebook c# Sdk to develop whatever you want to develop.

And all these info is valid for you IFF you are developing in c# my friend.

Answer (score 0):

use this get request

https://graph.facebook.com/'your facebook page ID'/events?access_token=' your application token'&limit='number of events wanted'&after=1&fields=owner,name,description,cover,id

first you must create a facebook application and get its "app token"

In the fileds column you can specify the details you want about the event using the names in facebook API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/