# Getting the events of a page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been trying to get a list of events of a page for some time now. Tried fql, events.get but nothing seems to work. The closest I got to is an error:
Requires valid signature
I tried something like here: [Get a list of events owned by a facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906846/get-a-list-of-events-owned-by-a-facebook-page)
ended up with something like this:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT eid, name, creator.id FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = XXXXX)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a page's event just by calling the graph api call `/<page_id>/events`. You can check what data you can get from a page on the Facebook's [graph api page node](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) documentation page.

```
$params = array('access_token' => $my_valid_access_token);
$page_id = '135559539828390';
$res = $fb->api('/' . $page_id . '/events', 'GET', $params);
var_dump($res);
```

Which returns:

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Event"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2010-12-30T20:00:00+0000"
      ["end_time"]=>
      string(24) "2010-12-30T23:00:00+0000"
      ["location"]=>
      string(6) "Moscow"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "114420411963816"
    }
  }
  ...
```

You can also create events [using POST queries on this node](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).

Comment: That does not work, getting this url:
http://graph.facebook.com/page_id/events
results in a JSON respons:
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}

Comment: The only way it worked for me is if I create a FB Application and use its application ID and application secret to request a token, then I use the token to request the events of the page. Is there no other way to request events without having to create an application? The events are already a public thing for a page, why the authentication?

Comment: I think Facebook wants to keep a certain control on these informations and wants developers to use a valid application to get these informations "offline" (ie: without using facebook's UI).